# Split Spark Dataframe into train and test

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I want to split my Spark Dataframe into train and test with the following conditions -

1. I want to be able to reproduce the split, which means that for each
   time for the same DataFrame, I will be able to to the same split.
2. The split should be taken from each unique value of a column name sequence-id.

Currently, I do it by converting the Dataframe into Pandas Dataframe and doing the following -

```
test_padnas = df.toPandas()
train_frac = 0.8

train = test_padnas.sort_values(by='sequence_id','timestamp']).groupby('sequence_id',group_keys=False).apply(lambda df: df.sample(frac=train_frac,random_state=200))
test=test_padnas.drop(train.index)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your df is a Spark DataFrame you can use the `randomSplit()` function that splits your DataFrame based on the weights percentages.

Furthermore it accept a **seed** that you can use to initialize the pseudorandom number generator that randomly splits the data and so have the same split each time.

```
train, test = df.randomSplit(weights=[0.8,0.2], seed=200)
```